# Scala pattern matching with manifest

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

[This great daily Scala article](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/overcoming-type-erasure-in-matching-1.html) describes how to overcome type erasure in matching.  I'm trying to apply the technique to transform an IndexesSeq of parameterised types, but the matches are failing.  Why is this, and how can I fix it?

```
object Example extends App{
    class TableColumn[T](
        val values: IndexedSeq[T], 
        val name: Option[String] = None
    )(implicit val m: Manifest[T])

    class Def[C](implicit desired : Manifest[C]) {
        def unapply[X](c : X)(implicit m : Manifest[X]) : Option[C] = {
            //println("m.toString+", "+desired.toString)
            def sameArgs = desired.typeArguments.zip(m.typeArguments).forall {
                case (desired,actual) => desired >:> actual
            }
            if (desired >:> m && sameArgs) Some(c.asInstanceOf[C])
            else None
         }
    }

    val IntTableColumn = new Def[TableColumn[Int]]
    val DoubleTableColumn = new Def[TableColumn[Double]]

    class Analysis(data: IndexedSeq[TableColumn[_]]){
        val transformedData = data.map{_ match{
            case IntTableColumn(tc) => println("Column of Int! "+ tc)
            case DoubleTableColumn(tc) => println("Column of Double! "+ tc)
            case _ => println("no match")
        }}
    }

    new Analysis(IndexedSeq(
            new TableColumn(IndexedSeq(1,2,3)),
            new TableColumn(IndexedSeq(1.0,2.0,3.0))
    ))
}
```

If I uncomment the line in Def then I see lines such as

```
prototype.Example$TableColumn[_ <: Any], prototype.Example$TableColumn[Int]
```

suggesting that the _ in the Analysis constructor is the problem, but I don't know what else to put in there.

Comment: Did you read in the article this phrase: "It is critical to notice the use of the typeArguments of the manifest. This returns a list of the manifests of each typeArgument. You cannot simply compare desired == m because manifest comparisons are not deep. There is a weakness in this code in that it only handles generics that are 1 level deep."?  The surrounding discussion won't tell you precisely how to fix it, but it should tell you why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rex: I got lost in some of the finer points of the article, but now you point it out I see the problem and will have a think about whether I can address it in some other way. Thanks

Comment: There are actually two problems: one is the nesting and the other is that you have multiple types in one list, which requires type widening.  I think you're going to want some `isAssignableFrom`s in the final solution, but unfortunately I don't have time to write a solution myself right now.

Comment: Since you've found the answer, you should answer your own question so it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comments from Rex Kerr I've cobbled together something that I think works.  It can probably done more elegantly/generally, but it seems to get the job done for now:

```
object Example extends App{
    class TableColumn[T](
            val values: IndexedSeq[T], 
            val name: Option[String] = None
    )(implicit val m: Manifest[T])

    class TableColumnMatcher[T](implicit desired: Manifest[T]){
        def unapply(tc: TableColumn[_]): Option[TableColumn[T]] = {
            if(tc.m == desired) Some(tc.asInstanceOf[TableColumn[T]])
            else None
        }
    }
    object TableColumnMatcher{
        lazy val IntTC = new TableColumnMatcher[Int]
        lazy val DoubleTC = new TableColumnMatcher[Double]
    }


    class Analysis(data: IndexedSeq[TableColumn[_]]){
        import TableColumnMatcher._
        val transformedData = data.map{_ match{
            case IntTC(tc) => println("Column of Ints!"); 
            case DoubleTC(tc) => println("Column of Doubles!")
            case _ => println("no match")
        }}
    }

    new Analysis(IndexedSeq(
            new TableColumn(IndexedSeq(1,2,3)),
            new TableColumn(IndexedSeq(1.0,2.0,3.0))
    ))
}
```